# How to ensure the data inserted in HBase via OpenTSDB?

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

I have try to store the huge amount of data into HBase using OpenTSDB. once i plot the datapoints in TSDB UI,it can show data points what i have inserted.

I aware that inserted data only can able to plot in opentsdb UI .. Is there any option to ensure the data points written in hbase without TSDDB UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a query request to OpenTSDB. For example:

```
http://tsdbHost:tsdbPort/api/query?start=1h-ago&m=sum:proc.stat.cpu{type=idle}
```

- tsdbHost - OpenTSDB host address
- tsdbPort - OpenTSDB port
- start=1h-ago - time range argument
- m=sum:proc.stat.cpu - aggregation function and metric
- type=idle - tags of metric

You can read more about queries structure in [Official OpenTSDB docs](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html).